# Can not delete question, that turned out to be wrong

Tags: flutter, istio, knative, metallb, cilium

Update: This was not Flutter, is is a network issue!

I can not delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in the browser console for error messages?

My first guess would be that some of the resources served by the application are being served with an incorrect hostname, i.e. `http://localhost/path/to/my.css`, which won't work if the application is actually running at `http://myservice.default.mydomain.com/`.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. Sadly it is not that

Comment: Are there any errors in the console log? What about the developer tools network request panel?

Comment: Nothing, apart from "Loading from service worker timed out after 4000 millisecond"

Comment: Do you know if any CORS,  Access-Control-Allow-Origin is needed?

Comment: Those should only be needed if you're loading resources from some _other_ authority (host).